# begin(split) not working

Tags: math-mode, split

I am trying to split my equation but it isn't working on output for some reason. This is my input

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}

    P(x=k) = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} * (\frac{\lambda}{n})^k * (1-\frac{\lambda}{n}})^{n-k} \\
    
    Let n \rightarrow \infty \\
    P(x=k) \\
    \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} * (\frac{\lambda}{n})^k * (1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{n-k}
    
    
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

What do I do?
```

Comment: blank lines are note allowed in math mode

Comment: Secondly there is an `}` too much in `(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}})`

Comment: Thirdly, since this is not numbered you would just have used `align*` instead of `equation*` and dropped `split`. Fourthly, why use an alignment construction when you don't have any alignments (alignment points are marked by `&`'s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It compiles if (a) you remove the extra `}` and (b) removes the blank lines (not allowed in math mode)

Thus this compiles

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
    P(x=k) = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} * (\frac{\lambda}{n})^k * (1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{n-k} \\
    Let n \rightarrow \infty \\
    P(x=k) \\
    \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} * (\frac{\lambda}{n})^k * (1-\frac{\lambda}{n})^{n-k}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Though this probably looks better

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  P(x=k) &= \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \cdot \left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^k
  \cdot \left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k}
  \\
  \intertext{Let $n \rightarrow \infty$:}
  \\
  P(x=k) &=
  \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} \cdot
  \left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^k \cdot
  \left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{n-k}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is what I did

- used `\cdot` not `*` as multiplication
- used `\left( ... \right)` around the fracions (one one the few placed where I normally don't manually scale
- switched to `align*` to get `\intertext` support and added alignment

Comment: Thank you so much @daleif it worked

Comment: @SachinPrabhuRam remember you can accept an answer by clicking the check mark next to it.